How to search as if from normal mode from an autocommand?
I've got some templates that I use for new files, and I'd like to be able to set myself up to execute a search within those new files as soon as they launch, and, ideally (and this is the part I'm struggling with), to have that be as if I'd done the search interactively from normal-mode after reading in the template.  So, for example, I've currently got, in my ~/.vimrc:
" read in my template:
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  r ~/etc/templates/new.html
" delete the blank line at the beginning that :r leaves:
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  1d
" My first attempt, which gets me to the right line,
" but not to the position on the line where XXX appears:
" autocmd BufNewFile  *.html  /XXX
" Further attempts to search, which only partly work:
" (note: I'm using just one of the following variations
" at a time; these are just the different
" things I've tried.)
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  normal /XXX^M
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  normal /XXX/^M
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  execute "normal /XXX\<CR>"
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  execute "normal /XXX/\<CR>"

(Also note: in my file, that's a literal ^M (aka carriage return) on those first two, not ^M, as it is here.)
The r and the 1d parts work great:

The template gets read in to my buffer, and
the blank line at the beginning (a side effect of using :r) gets deleted.

But then I try to do the search, and... well...  Using any of the variations shown for doing the search will get me the first part of what I want — positioning my cursor on the first instance of XXX from the read-in template file (which I use as a placeholder for stuff I want to change in the non-template version of the things I'm creating).
Alas, then going on to press n does not search for XXX again, as I would want it to, but instead searches for the next instance of whatever I happen to have last searched for the last time I was running vim (as saved in my ~/.viminfo file).
Is there some way I can get the new search to be added to last-pattern?
(last-pattern being the name for the help section that talks about how the last search is stored, though I don't know how to change it other than executing a search interactively — it doesn't show up in :set all and attempting :set last-pattern gives an error.)
(Note: my search does get saved into the history of searches that shows up if I type q/ (from normal mode), and if I then select it from there, it becomes the last-pattern, but I'm hoping to get it to just be in last-pattern directly from my vimrc's autocmds.)

@Friedrich - then there'll just be a blank line at the END of the file, instead of at the beginning.  to wit, commands in a shell: echo 1line > 1line; echo ':r 1line\n:wq' > script1; echo ':0r 1line\n:wq' > script2; vim -s script1 file1; vim -s script2 file2; wc -l ????? — You'll see both file1 and file2 are 2 lines, not 1, like 1line

Why should text files end with a newline?

@Friedrich yeah, my template already ends with a newline.  When I use 0read, I get an extra one.  No thanks.

The order in which you add autocommands is theoretically the one in which they will be executed but…

autocommands can be removed,
autocommands can fail silently, which can be a problem if an autocommand depends on the outcome of a previous one.

Chaining autocommands in an imperative way, like you do, is a bit too confident. Furthermore, all those autocommands you are piling up waste memory for no reason and are unnecessarily hard to read.
You should use one autocommand:
augroup Mytemplates
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile *.html call HTMLTemplate()
augroup END

and handle everything in a simple function:
function! HTMLTemplate()
    r ~/etc/templates/new.html
    1d
    let @/ = "XXX"
    execute "normal /\<CR>"
endfunction

Possible improvements:

Be more explicit about addresses (1r instead of r).
Use 1d_ to cut the empty line into the "black hole" register so that the unnamed register and the numbered registers are not polluted. See :help registers.
Use normal n to perform the search without having to deal with :help :normal's quoting/escaping weirdness. You can also use :help search().
Skip the :read/:delete dance completely with :help readfile() and :help setline(). This also prevents your template from becoming the buffer's "alternate file".
Handle exceptions.

Here is the same function as above, with some of the suggestions applied:
function! HTMLTemplate()
    call setline(1, readfile(expand("~/etc/templates/new.html")))
    let @/ = "XXX"
    normal n
endfunction


I'm confused. I thought "Vim always adds the {cmd} after existing autocommands, so that the autocommands execute in the order in which they were given." (quoting from :help :autocmd)

They can be removed or fail silently. Having an autocommand depend on something done by a previous one is just not a good idea.

As indicated in :help autocmd-searchpat (see also: :help template), autocmds don't save searches.  But, it's easy to get what you're looking for by setting the @/ variable, as such:
" read in the template (could also use 0read):
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  r ~/etc/templates/new.html
" delete an extraneous blank line ($d if using 0read):
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  1d
" set a string to search for:
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  let @/ = "XXX"
" execute the search as if done in normal mode:
autocmd BufNewFile    *.html  execute "normal /\<CR>"


Too many unnecessary autocommands that could end up being executed in any order.

What you're trying to do is already covered by Vim's built-in documentation.
See :help template for a lot of clues related to inserting template files.
By the way, it suggests to use :0read rather than :read and :1delete.
You may also find 1;/XXX to search from the top of the file below :help autocommand-pattern helpful.
To address the actual question:
your original command /XXX is the correct one to use.
The n command does not work because the last search pattern register is restored after an autocommand finishes.
This is intended behavior and documented in :help autocmd-searchpat immediately below :help template.
The workaround offered there is to explicitly set the / register through :let @/='XXX'.
Also see :help @/

The problem with [:]/XXX in the autocommand is that it doesn't position the cursor on the right column, as I understand it. Perhaps feedkeys() is actually appropriate here?

Thanks for this.  As mentioned in a comment replying to an apparently-now-deleted other comment, 0read doesn't really help me all that much, because that just leaves a blank line after the template, instead of before it.  The @/ stuff, though, leads me to just what I needed!  (Which I'm going to post as my own answer for the sake of something concise -- my tendency for verbosity notwithstanding.)

@lindes I chose to remove my comment since :0r is in the answer. No need to have it twice.

Fair enough.  Except... well, I don't know if you'd seen my reply to it by the time you deleted it, but I hadn't seen your answer by the time I posted my reply (it didn't exist when I started typing, as far as I know), so, it kinda breaks the conversation a bit.  Ah well.  I don't feel like re-writing my comment here, so I'll just leave the reference to it.

@D.BenKnoble how comes every time I write an answer you leave a comment suggesting a vastly superior approach? :-D

just like to polish. And on mobile suggesting improvements is easier than writing a full answer
